# MySQL position in recordset

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm ordering a recordset like this:

```
SELECT * FROM leaderboards ORDER BY time ASC, percent DESC
```

Say I have the id of the record which relates to you, how can I find out what position it is in the recordset, as ordered above?

I understand if it was just ordered by say 'time' I could

```
SELECT count from table where time < your_id
```

But having 2 ORDER BYs has confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable to assign a counter:

```
SELECT *, @ctr := @ctr + 1 AS RowNumber
FROM leaderboards, (SELECT @ctr := 0) c
ORDER BY time ASC, percent DESC
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to get say the 6th through 10th rows or something like that?

Comment: Meant you were ever so slightly faster giving essentialy the same response as I

Comment: @vollie - I was replying to a question the OP had in the comments but has since removed. I know all about the "slightly faster" because I'm normally on the losing end :) Thanks for your upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM leaderboards lb cross join
     (select * from leaderboards where id = MYID) theone
WHERE lb.time < theone.time or
      (lb.time = theone.time and lb.percent >= theone.percent);
```

This assumes that there are no duplicates for `time, percent`.

Comment: Gordon, if there are no duplicates in first field for `ORDER` clause, I believe there's no sense in second order condition at all (order will always the same as in first column since values are unique)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo . . . I mean the pairs are distinct, not the time values.